# Trying to compare the fetched result with the user input

Tags: database

I am new to Drupal and I am facing some issues right now. I am making a hall booking website, so I have a table named "halls" with following fields: HallID, HallName, Capacity, Type, Price.

[image: db table]

I created a new module and the form that I need. On the booking page I have 2 dropdown menus, type of hall the hall the user needs. (each hall has different capacity and price). Right after these I have 2 text fields, Capacity and Price.

[image: bookingform]

So what I do is I retrieve from database the Capacity value for the Hall and the Type the user has chosen and right after submitting I am trying to compare the input from the Capacity field with the earlier retrieved result. I am getting "Success" message every time, even if Capacity field value is higher than the value in the db...

Here I am retrieving data intro dropdown menus from db and creating simple forms:

```
function booking_form($form, &$form_state){
$table = 'halls';
$query1 = db_select($table, 'h')
    ->fields('h', array('HallName'))
    ->distinct();

$query2 = db_select($table, 'h')
    ->fields('h', array('Type'))
    ->distinct();

$result1 = $query1->execute()->fetchAll();
$result2 = $query2->execute()->fetchAll();


$hall_name = array();
foreach($result1 as $res1){
    $hall_name[] = $res1->HallName;
}

$hall_type = array();
foreach($result2 as $res2){
    $hall_type[] = $res2->Type;
}

$form['hall_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Select the hall type',
    '#options' => $hall_type,
);

$form['hall_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Select the hall',
    '#options' => $hall_name,
);

$form['nr_people'] = array(
    ...
);

$form['duration'] = array(
    ...
);

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('OK'),
);

return $form; }
```

After this comes the validation. At first I am querying the value of Capacity field based on HallName and HallType selected:

```
function booking_form_validate($form, &$form_state){

$table = 'halls';
$query = db_select($table, 'h')
    ->fields('h', array('Capacity'))
    ->condition('h.Type', $form_state['values']['hall_type'], '=')
    ->condition('h.HallName', $form_state['values']['hall_name'], '='); 

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

$capacity_val= array();
foreach($result as $res){
    $capacity_val[] = $res->Capacity;
}

if($form_state['values']['nr_people'] > $capacity_val){
    form_set_error('nr_people', t('Max. capacity exceeded!'));
} }
```

So what is wrong? I am not fetching correctly? Any help would be appreciated. And how do I print the value that I fetch from db, in simple php I used "echo" but here in Drupal is not that simple. Btw I am using Drupal 7. Thanks.